# Invoke tasklist /m with subprocess hangs

Tags: python, python-2.7, tasklist

Here is something curious which I cannot explain. Consider this code segment:

```
import subprocess

command = ['tasklist.exe', '/m', 'imm32.dll']
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
```

The call to `communicate()` hung and I had to break out with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. After that, the tasklist process was still running, which I had to kill it with `taskkill.exe`. Take a look at the behaviors of tasklist.exe in the table below:

```
| Command                             | Behavior |
|-------------------------------------|----------|
| ['tasklist.exe', '/m', 'imm32.dll'] | Hung     |
| ['tasklist.exe', '/m']              | Hung     |
| ['tasklist.exe']                    | OK       |
```

It seems when the `/m` flag is present, the process does not return. It just runs forever. I have also tried the following and it also hung:

```
os.system('tasklist.exe /m imm32.dll')
```

How can I launch this command and not hang?

## Update

It turns out that the `communicate` call did not hang, but took up to 10 minutes to finished, something that would take a couple of seconds if I ran the command from the cmd.exe prompt. I believe this has to do with buffering, but have not found a way to make it to finish faster.

Comment: if `/m` makes it hand indefinitely, why not remove `/m`? Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I need the `/m` flag to locate which process is using this DLL, see doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tasklist)

Comment: Testing on Windows 10, Python 64-bit, version 3.6.3, I can't reproduce. I get a whole mess of output in the `out` variable running your *exact* set of commands in an `ipython` interactive session. Presumably either your environment is different in a way that influences it, or you're not providing an accurate repro.

Comment: My environment is Windows 10, Python 2.7

Comment: So is saying "It's been 10ish years, write new code in the modern language?" out of line here? ;-) Sorry, I don't even have Py2 installed anymore; `subprocess` was *heavily* modified in the transition to Py3 IIRC, so there could be some bug that has long been fixed hurting you. You could try installing the PyPI `subprocess32` package and using that; it's supposed to be a backport of the Py3 era `subprocess` module.

Comment: I just tried the same script with Python 3.4.0 and experienced the same hang. Why 3.4.0? The majority of my company is still on 2.7 and we have been slowly moving to 3.4.0.

Comment: I just noticed that "tasklist /m" hangs if used in a post-build event for a project in Visual Studio (where it is run as a sub-process).  My post-build event in full is: tasklist /m "$(TargetFileName)", because I'm trying to track down why I'm getting sporadic build errors strong-name signing a module after it is built.  I came across the current page after a search for a solution or explanation why it seems to be hanging.